# Hive query: Match string with list of keywords

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table with tweets about movies and a table with keywords mapped to movie titles

keyword example:

```
title                 keyword
------                -------
3 Days to Kill        3daystokill
3 Days to Kill        3 days to kill
12 Years a Slave      12YearsASlave
```

tweets example:

```
id              text
------          -------
125675146       3daystokill sucks!
125673498       3 days to kill is awesome!
239873985       I like 12 Years a Slave :)
```

I would like to be able to find the tweets matching the keywords for a certain movie title. For example, I want to find all the tweets that mention keywords from 3 Days to Kill (3daystokill and 3 days to kill).

I thought something like this, but the results are empty :(

```
SELECT k.keyword, t.text
FROM keywords k JOIN tweets t
ON t.text = CONCAT('%',k.keyword,'%')
WHERE k.title = "3 Days to Kill";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `like`, not `=`:

```
SELECT k.keyword, t.text
FROM keywords k JOIN
     tweets t
     ON t.text like CONCAT('%', k.keyword, '%')
WHERE k.title = '3 Days to Kill';
```

EDIT:

I was not aware that HiveQL limited `like` to only wildcards at the beginning or end.  One option is `rlike`.  Another is `instr()`:

```
SELECT k.keyword, t.text
FROM keywords k JOIN
     tweets t
     ON instr(t.text, k.keyword) > 0
WHERE k.title = '3 Days to Kill';
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it isn't allowed in HiveQL: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:8 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN ''%''

Comment: EDIT gives the same error, I think you can only use = in hive joins? SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 4:8 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0'

Comment: Only equality joins, outer joins, and left semi joins are supported in Hive: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins

Comment: @user2440006 . . . I was thinking of HQL.  Can you do it with a `cross join` and condition in the `where` clause?  Or by faking a condition such as `1=1`.  On the other hand, there is probably a more hive'ish way of getting it done.

Comment: Cross join did the trick!

    SELECT k.title, t.text
    FROM keywords k CROSS JOIN tweets t
    WHERE t.text LIKE CONCAT('%',k.keyword,'%');

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the below helps.. :( But have just given a try.

```
select case when
replace(keyword,' ',null) = '3daystokill'
then keyword
end
from keywords
```

Comment: Where in the query should I put this? I am not completely sure what you are aiming for.

Comment: If it contains "3 days to kill" in any format.. with or without space, you will be able to pick it up. so if that is the requirement, then join the query i gave with the tweets table

Comment: I see what you mean now, but keywords won't always be with or without spaces. They can also be like (300 movie, 300 rise of an empire,...) but I appreciate the effort!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Hive StatisticsAndDataMining Fuction context_ngrams()

```
SELECT context_ngrams(sentences(lower(tweet)), 2, 100 [, 1000]) FROM twitter;
```